# physical intuition behind quasi-bound state formation in feshbach resonance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, nuclear-physics

In Feshbach resonance, by scattering theory formalism it is found that the resonance in cross-section happens when bound state energy of the closed channel is near to the scattering state energy of the open channel. This is explained for the case of 2 atoms interacting via a Lienard Jones potential (for far away distances) and insertion of an extra term in the potential due to hyperfine interaction at close distances. Explanation for resonance is given as follows :- the scattering state continuum energy of the 2 atoms on addition of the hyperfine interaction at small separation distances goes into the excitations of the internal states leading to a lowering of the kinetic energy of the 2 atoms and formation of a quasi-bound state. Can this point be explained in more detail ?  how are the excitations in the internal states coming from the hyperfine interaction term and leading to a quasi-bound state (bound state with a finite lifetime) is not clear to me.